# Eyepiece projection photography

Tags: amateur-observing

Nothing is showing up in the viewfinder of camera when I try to do eyepiece projection photography.could I have something set up wrong?

Comment: Yes you probably have done *something* wrong, but you will need to give more details if you want more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be focus and or a faint image in the viewfinder, try looking at a distant object in daytime.

Of course unless you are using a dslr type camera the viewfinder will not be looking through the main optics anyway so wont show anything.